# Setting sublime text and pylint to work with django "Unable to import 'django.db'."

Tags: python, django, pylint

I am confused about how to configure the settings of Sublime Text and pylint to work together nicely. I am beginning to work on a Django project. I have installed SublimeLinter, SublimeLinter-pylint and Djaneiro. I have played with various settings in the sublime-project file. But I can't seem to stop pylint from reporting an error "Unable to import 'django.db'."

How do I do that?